# Android shell script to remove all files and folders in a directory except one

Tags: android, sh

Right now I am using `rm -r /blaa/*` to delete all folders and files in the `blaa` directory. What I am looking for is a way to remove all folders and files in the `blaa` directory except if the folder is named `abc`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In Linux:**

There are many ways to this; however I believe the best way to do this is to simply use the "`find`" tool.

```
find ! -iname "abc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

We can easily find and delete the every file and folder that is not named "abc".

```
find      - to find files
! -iname  - to filter files/folders, the "!" means not
-exec     - to execute a command on every file
rm -rf    - remove/delete files -r for folders as well and -f for force
"{} \;"   - allows the commands to be used on every file
```

**In Android:**

Since you can't use "`rm -rf`" and when you use "`rm -r`" it will delete the folder "`.`" which ends up deleting everything.

I am guessing you have "root" on your phone because you can use the "find" tool.

```
find ! -iname "abc" | sed 1d | xargs rm -r

find      - to find files
! -iname  - to filter files/folders, the "!" means not
|         - pipe sends data to next command
sed       - replace text/output
"1d"      - removes first line when you do "find ! -iname" by itself
xargs     - runs commands after pipe
rm -r     - remove/delete files, "-r" for recursive for folders
```

Edit: Fixed and tested in Android

You can easily change this to suite your needs, please let me know if this helps!

---

#### The Adopted Solution

...and the final hoorah... This is what worked for the use case (helps to sum up the comments below as well):

```
find ! -iname "abc" -maxdepth 1 -depth -print0 | sed '$d' | xargs -0 rm -r;
```

Notes:

- `-depth`            — reverses the output (so you dont delete sub-dirs first
- `-maxdepth 1`       — kind of voids the use of -depth, but hey... this says only output contents of the current directory and not sub-dirs (which are removed by the -r option anyway)
- `-print0` and `-0`    — splits on line feeds instead of white space (for dirs with space in the name)
- `sed "$d"`          — says to remove the last line (cause its now reversed). The last line is just a period which including would make the call delete everything in the directory (and subs!)

I am sure someone can tighten this up, but it works and was a great learning op!

Thanks again to Jared Burrows(and the Unix community in general — go team!)    — [MindWire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/525541/mindwire)

Comment: When I give it a try I get: rm failed for -rf, No such file or directory ... and it keeps running continuously until I Ctrl-Z it.

Comment: O I'm sorry, the android version of rm only allows -r and -R. Let me correct this.

Comment: Ok so getting close and thank you for the verbose response. It fails when there are sub folders or files (eg. /blaa/qqq/rrr.xml when run inside of /blaa. From what I can tell its deleting the folder first, then trying to hit up the next find entry which is a sub folder or file of the directory just deleted. Perhaps there is a way of reversing the find results (but maybe its not the most efficient way?)

Comment: Just found that adding the -depth command reverses the order of the results... but also breaks the whole sed 1d.. buut, if you use: find ! -iname "abc" -depth | sed '$d' | xargs rm -r it works ($d removes the last line). What I am not sure of is if this is best way or a just a sh noob's way around?

Comment: For Android, they have removed a lot of great commands from the Kernel as it is, that is why someone created Busybox. MindWire, this is a great learning website, no one here is ever a noob :) We can all learn and share good information and as long as it suits your needs I am happy :)